# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps V2 and maps utils to show clusters. When I run my app on device with Kitkat  then the app crashes (but works on M and L devices). I already spent 3 days to solve this issue, but unfortunately no look on this. Has anyone an idea what is going on here?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.pokespotter, PID: 11479
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator
  at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer.<init>(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:133)
  at com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager.<init>(ClusterManager.java:72)
  at com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager.<init>(ClusterManager.java:64)
  at com.pokespotter.ActivityMap.onMapReady(ActivityMap.java:1409)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
  at xz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
  at maps.ad.u$5.run(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle configs:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.pokespotter"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
        compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

Comment: @Jimmy plz update your google play service "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0" plz check this site: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config and also check : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: yes indeed, that fixed the issue. thank you guys